# Two and One sided limits

Tags: limits

I understand the difference and how to get each but when do you use one or the other?

Does it depend on the problem? When would you want to take the right and left limits vs when you would just take the limit as it approaches whatever?

Comment: Just depends on the problem, for instance, say you're modeling the speed of an object as a function of its weight, and you want to see what happens to its speed as its weight goes to zero. In this case you'd probably only care about a one sided limit, because the notion of negative weight probably isn't applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather general question but here are some things.

A two sided limit exists iff both limits go to the same value.

We often use one sided limits for evaluating what a function does near discontinuities or end points.  Think about a function that is only defined on (a,b).  The two sided limit not defined for x=a or x=b.  However there is a one sided limit at both ends.

In general two sided limits are what are used most commonly because the one sided limits both tend to equal each other if there is a jump discontinuity.

One sided limits basically only matter when there is a at weird spots in a function.  Discontinuities, end points or infinities.

Comment: I know it's general but I am refreshing math skills from over 15 years ago and needed an explanation I could not find on google

Comment: Not a problem.  I was just letting you know that there is a lot to this question that I can't fully answer.

Comment: No you answered all I needed, just wanted a simple clarification. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just depends on the problem, for instance, say you're modeling the speed of an object as a function of its weight, and you want to see what happens to its speed as its weight goes to zero. In this case you'd probably only care about a one sided limit, because the notion of negative weight probably isn't applicable.

On the other hand, if you were wondering what happened to its speed as you approached 5 weight units, then you may care about both sides, because weights above and below 5 could both be possible.